# How I bring all explorer.exe windows to the front at the same time like OSX Finder do?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

Well, I am working in a big game project, and I must sometimes copy and move massive amount of files between several folders, it is not uncommon to have to work with 3 or even 4 folders at once.

On OSX this is a breeze, when you click on "Finder" it displays your last window configuration, bringing all windows to the front (but with correct ordering between themselves).

On Windows you have to alt+tab or click on the taskbar on each one you want to use manually, this is bogging down my productivity enough to make me take my time to write the question here.

So, how I make Windows explorer.exe windows behave like OSX Finder ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seemly there is no way to hide all explorer.exe windows at once, or
>   call them all back at once.

Say you have 5 Explorer windows open, and they are in a stack on the Taskbar.

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Right-Click the stack and select "Minimize all windows".

[image]

To restore them, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Right-Click the stack and select "Restore all windows".

[image]

Screenshots are from Windows 7, but it's the same on 8. :)

More info on similar in-built Windows features/commands you may find handy for your tasks:

- [The Power User's Guide to the Windows 7 Taskbar](http://lifehacker.com/5532578/the-power-users-guide-to-the-windows-7-taskbar)
- [Windows Snap](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/snap)
- [128 useful Keyboard Shortcuts for Windows 7](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_7.html)

Comment: alright, this does not work either, when ONE window is open (like because I clicked on a zip file), the "restore all" get greyed out. ¬¬

Comment: @speeder I'm not sure what you mean.  If you only have one window open, then yeah, the "... all windows" commands will be unavailable.  If it's only just one window, then just minimize and maximize as you normally would?

Comment: I mean I have several windows loaded, only one is focused, then I cannot use "restore all windows" to restore the others... So if I click on a .zip file, I need to manually restore each window I want to paste files into from the .zip.

Answer (score 1):

Hold Shift key.
Right click on explorer icon on start toolbar.
There should be several options like opening them all in cascade mode or just resuming all the windows at once (if they were minimized before).